# How do I do live Markdown previewing as I'm writing it?

Tags: buffers, markdown, previewing

How can I do that either in a different buffer or even in the current buffer?

I'm trying to do Github README.md and other Github rendering of Markdown (for notes and such),

Comment: First glance this seems straightforward to do using `markdown-export` and `eww`, driven from a change notification hook and timer. But it seems like the interesting part would be determining what part of the `eww` buffer HTML corresponds to `point` in the markdown buffer (so the they could scroll "in sync").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pretty long but efficient solution.

1. Install `simple-httpd` and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `httpd-start`.
2. Install `markdown` from your system's package manager.
3. Open your markdown buffer and run <kbd>markdown-export</kbd>. That produces a HTML file in the same directory.
4. Open that HTML file.
5. Install `impatient-mode` and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `impatient-mode`.
6. Go back to your markdown file.

Finally, evaluate this code:

```cl
(defun markdown-export-continuous (&optional output-file)
  (interactive)
  (let ((input-file (buffer-file-name))
        (output-file (markdown-export-file-name ".html")))
    (when output-file
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect output-file)
        (erase-buffer)
        (insert
         (shell-command-to-string
          (format "markdown %s" input-file)))
        (save-buffer)))))
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'markdown-export-continuous t t)
```

Note that the `add-hook` statement needs to be local to Markdown, so run it in that buffer.

After all this, open your browser on `http://localhost:8080/imp/` and
it will refresh each time you <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>.

Comment: I'm seeing the html file in localhost:8080/imp, but I have to click on it to see it, and C-x C-s doesn't seem to refresh. Or is that intended?

Comment: In addition, instead of just markdown-export, is there a way to do Github-flavored markdown export instead?

Answer (score 9):

As of [markdown-mode 2.1](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/rev-2-1), this is functionality is provided in `markdown-live-preview-mode` (bound to `C-c C-c l`).

It uses eww for rendering the HTML. Screenshot:

[image: live preview of markdown]